# PHP dont trigger on form submit when using Action property

Tags: php, forms, action

I have picked up site from other developer and i dont understand at all why it works when we have 
page is `https://site.com/form.php`

```
  <form method="POST" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    </form>
```

and as soon as i add `action="form.php"` or `action="https://site.com/form.php"` it stop working upon submitting. It does not throw error but it supposed to go trough several functions and it does not. Maybee because he suck down value from address bar in his function i need to take look but is there other way why it might happen?
Originally it was not HTTPS it was HTTP can this have any effect now i use mod_rewrite to change it all to HTTPS...

**This is the only code on the page where the form is submitted  that actually process something, can you explain why it cease to work if i specify action= property in form?!**

```
    require_once "pdf.php";
       $obj=new common();

    if($_POST['Submit'])
    {
        switch($type)
        {
          case "docx":
           $obj->docx_pdf();
          break;
          case "doc":
           $obj->doc_pdf();
          break;
          case "jpg":
           $obj->image_pdf();
          break;    
        }
    }

   if(($_POST['PDF']) || ($_POST['PDFYES']))
   //$obj->generate_pdf();
        $obj->over_all();

   if($_POST['Delete'])
        $obj->delete_files($_POST);

   $obj->get_pdf_file();
   $obj->display_all();
   $objSmarty->display("form.tpl");
```

Comment: stops working how exactly? what do you see?

Comment: Sidenote: that form should have an action defined. Anyway, when it's not, or is empty `action=""`, it defaults to the current url. So I don't know why it's not working in your second example; please be clearer

Comment: I updated my qauestion. I know thats why i am shocked because i specify same url in action as the url of the form (form.php)!
Functions are like 1000 lines but it does not have $_SERVER variable so i dont think it has to do with url of POST request?!

Comment: Compare the HTTP request in both cases. If you're just changing the html, you can only be affecting the request.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the form used to be submitted using some javascript. So some element having a `onclick` defined, and when you click it, the form gets submitted. This would explain why no `action` attribute was defined in the first place but a `name` attribute was.